# Add subcategories in a filtered API Restful resource

Tags: rest, express, restful-architecture, api-design, restful-url

I'll give an example as the title might sound a bit confusing.

How to build a resource path for something like that:

GET /courses/?language=english&active=true/units

I want to filter the courses (not using an id as usually) and then get the units of this result. How would you do that? I guess using question marks between the path is not allowed.

Comment: Depends on your server setup, what DB you are using, etc.

Comment: I don't worry about the implementation. I'm just not sure how the path for this resource should look like in a Restful way.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend a little on your DB schema of **what is a "course" and a "unit"**. The whole point on using the RESTful way is to always build requests and urls resource-specific.

But let's say that one course has X units on it. Here's what i would do to make a RESTful path to that request:

Due to the path problem of filtering courses AND using the /unit suffix, it can be done by **adding another query parameter** that specifies what fields the request is supposed to return. Something like this:

> **GET /courses?language=english&active=true&fields=units**

That would filter the courses, and then return **only the 'units' field** on the response. As i said, depending on your DB and models, if the units are not stored inside the courses, it would be a **bad practice** to get them by requesting a /courses path. In that case, first request the courses that match the desired filter, and then make **another request to the /units** context sending i.e the courses ID's as query parameters.

Comment: I have 2 different tables, one for Courses and one for Units. There is a relation of one-to-many (one course can have many units).

As you said, I guess the only "Restful way" of getting the final result I want is sending 2 requests, although it doesn't seem to be very efficient.

Comment: You could also create a new context with only /units. I assume that every unit on a course that is 'english' and 'active' is automatically 'english' and 'active' too. So you would be making a GET /units?language=english&active=true, leaving to the back-end to handle the two tables but sending only units resource. For an example, in the GitHub API, you can do /user/issues, /organization/issues or simply /issues.